Row/Column transformation or shuffling for least square solution
Let's say I want to find the least square solution for minimum norm $||Ax -b||_2^{2}$, and consider the case where $x, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, so $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Now the solution can be iteratively found using $x^* = (A^TA)^{-1} A^T b$. Lets say some of the diagonal elements in $A^TA$ are zero, so it's not invertible. Is it allowed to do some row/ column transformations to invert it and use it in the above equation?
The inverse is preserved in row transformations, but are the solutions too?
If I can't directly use it (but I already know the operations), can I use those to get to the desired solution?

I tried my best to search through StackExchange, but if you find a similar question, please send the links to it.

What do you mean by "allowed to do some row/ column transformations" ?

From allowed, I meant that if I do some row transformations and then invert them, would the new inverse be meaningful in the least square solution sense?

If you do a row transformation, then determinant doesn't change (other than sign). So how will transformation ensure that $A^{T}A$ will become invertible ?

Let's suppose $f(x) =   \Vert Ax - b\Vert^{2}$ and you are trying to solve $\min f(x)$ and if $A$ has null space (that is when $A^{T}A$ is not invertible) then the solution to minimization problem is not unique. If $\tilde{x}$ is where minimum happens then you can take any element $t \in \mathcal{N}(A)$ and $f( \tilde{x} ) = f( \tilde{x} + t)$. As there are many possible solutions you have to ask what kind of solution you are seeking ? Any solution is okay with you ?

Okay, so this was my thought process. Check out this question. Now assume that my $A^T A$ has some zero elements in the diagonal and they can be arbitrarily in any position. So the idea is to shuffle some rows of the matrix so I can represent A as an invertible matrix and D as zero matrix. That block inverse formula only needs A to be invertible. Question is, can I directly use that inverted matrix or do I have to redo those shuffling after I find the inverse? I hope the idea is clearer now.

I checked the post you attached. For the block inverse matrix to work, we need not only $A$ to be invertible but also $D−CA^{−1}B$ and some other matrices. How will you ensure this ? Also what will you do when there are non zero diagonal elements. Like for example $A^{T}A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \ 1& 1\end{bmatrix}$ ?

I know there are assumptions on top of them as well, but let's consider that the inverse can be computed. If we have arrived at a solution, then can the inverse be used? (This is the main point of my question.)
